# Is there a good reason to not use bit operators instead of parseInt?

Tags: javascript, bit

I've lately started using bit operators instead of parseInt.

```
> 70.5|0
70
> "70.5"|0
70
> 0xFF|0
255
> "0xFF"|0
255
```

It casts everything into an integer. This has a sometimes useful side effect.

```
> 1+undefined|0
1
> 1+parseInt(undefined)
NaN
```

What it cannot do is this.

```
> "16px"|0
0
> parseInt("16px",10)
16
```

Other operators with the same effect.

```
> 70.5^0
70
> ~~70.5
70
> 70.5<<0
70
```

It's nice short notation for parseInt IMO.

Comment: It's definitively more clear if you use `parseInt`. Otherwise you will end up putting comments to explain what the trick does so no one confuses it with a syntax error.

Comment: It's a nice, short, _not very obvious_ way to parse an int. And to convert other things to 0 even when that doesn't make sense: the side effect you describe as useful (when used on undefined) is a side effect I'd describe as "unwanted", because how do you tell whether the value you just parsed was actually 0 originally? A good way to introduce hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: One other note to add. Numbers above 32-bits will turn out completely different when using bitwise OR, for example: `50000000000|0; // Returns -1539607552`

Answer (score 0):

For simple conversion of strings to numbers, unary '+' can be used. If maintainability matters, `Number(x)` is clearer.

For numbers with an alphabetic suffix, `parseInt` is pretty handy but it has issues if the radix is omitted and it's clunky to read.

Where simple truncation is required and speed matters, a bitwise operator is great but it is somewhat obfuscated, `Math.floor()`, `.round()` or `.ceil()` are clearer but (probably) slower.

They all have their quirks so just use what is best for each case.